# Changing the geolocation of a point in the map

Tags: qgis, coordinates, geolocation

I uploaded a vector layer with points = cities. After zooming in I found out that some cities are on wrong places. How can I change the geolocation for a specific point, city?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the layer is editable all you need to do is right click on the layer and select `Toggle Editing` and then in the `Digitizing Toolbar` select the `Move Feature(s)` button. Then you can click and drag the points however you want. When you are done moving your points select `Save Layer Edits` also in the `Digitizing Toolbar`. If the layer is not editable you will need to save the layer as something that is editable, and then make your changes to that layer.

Below is a screenshot of the Digitizing Toolbar.

[image: Digitizing Toolbar]

Descriptions of the buttons going left to right

1. Current Edits (Rollback, save, cancel, etc.)
2. Toggle Editing
3. Save Layer Edits
4. Add Feature
5. Add Circular Ring
6. Move Feature(s)
7. Node Tool
8. Delete Selected
9. Cut Features
10. Copy Features
11. Paste Features

Also if you want to change the coordinates of the points with specific values, you don't need a plugin to do that. You can select the `Node Tool` button and click on a point. This should bring up the `Vertex Editor` panel and you can change your X Y values directly in there. If the layer includes Z and or M values, the vertex editor will also allow you to edit the Z and or M values. Thanks [@mgri](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/87487/mgri) for reminding me about the possible need to change values directly by coordinates.

Answer (score 4):

The [solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/229821/87487) by [@TJ Rockfeller](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/56050/tj-rockefeller) leads to manually move the points.

Instead, if you need to move the point to a specific location (i.e. using specific coordinates), you may use the **Numerical Vertex Edit** plugin.

It's very simple to use:

1. Right click on the layer and select `Toggle Editing`;
2. Select the point you need to move;
3. Enter the new coordinates using the units of measure of the layer that you edit.

[image]

You may install it from `Plugins` > `Manage and Install Plugins`.