# QGIS Vertex Editor Coordinates

Tags: qgis

The Vertex Editor in QGIS is displaying x,y coordinates of the nodes in longitude and latitude. Is there any way to make it display the x,y coordinates in meters?

Comment: Vertex editor should use the same units as your project. What do you have now in Project - Properties - CRS?

Comment: My project used UTM coordinates, but the layer used lat/long coordinates. As answered by @Kazuhito, the Vertex Editor uses the layer's coordinate system, not the project's. So, I have to reproject the layer to a UTM CRS in order to use meters for x,y in the Vertex Editor.

Comment: Thanks, the second answer in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/229817/changing-the-geolocation-of-a-point-in-the-map/229821#229821 talks about CRS of the project, I will make an edit by the same.

Answer (score 3):

Vertex Editor simply shows the coordinates according to the Data Source (your layer's) CRS. This is useful, but can cause confusion especially when your project is 'on the fly' (OTF) mode.

Let's say you have 2 layers, one is in NAD83 (EPSG: 4269) and another is in NAD83/UTM zone 17N (EPSG: 26917).

When you select NAD83 layer and activate Vertex Editor it shows Latitude/Longitude. Then you switch to NAD83/UTM17N layer, it shows X,Y in meters.

Your data now has geographical coordinates (latlon). Please reproject your layer by `Save As` command to appropriate CRS in meters.